# JSP not showing &reg; or trademark symbol

Tags: jsp, utf-8, copyright-display

the jsp is not showing the ® symbol and the i am  having the below encoding

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

and the code is

```
<td>
    <c:out value="${value}"></c:out>
</td>
```

the ${value} is fetching from the DB and it contains `5 AP&reg;`.
when i hard code like `&reg;` then the symbol ® is coming if the same is passed from DB its not printing. also i tried unicodes(\u2122)

but no luck, please suggest with some example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the answer,i had added this property in  tag
   escapeXml="false"
its showing now  the symbols

```
<c:out value="${value}" escapeXml="false" />
```